# react useState (one variable only) with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am taking an example from [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/):

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I would like to extend this example with typescript. I get it to work, but I do not know if there is an easier way:

```
interface StateCount {
    count: number;
}

function Example() {
  const [countBox, setCount] = useState<StateCount>({count: 0});

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(countBox.count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now it's much more complicated to access the variable. Is it possible to declare it in this way:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState<StateCount>(0);
```

and access it again in this way?

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
```

Comment: Never tried ts with react but shouldn't `const [countBox, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
` be sufficient?

Comment: Sometimes it can be that easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `StateCount` as an interface of your state, than that's the way you should do it. Otherwise you can use

```
const [countBox, setCountBox] = useState<number>(0);

//and set it as
setCount(countBox + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't planning on adding any other members to StateCount then you can use the number type instead.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Typescript can also imply that the type is number because you're specifying an initial value.

If you are needing to add more members to your state, you can instead have multiple useState calls for each value you need; otherwise, you will have to access the specific member you're using.